# Visual studio 2013 and oracle - project properties problems

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2013

Hi I'm trying to create a new project in C# where I can include the oracle instantclient_12_1

I start by simple creating a project in C# (windows form project) but when I want to include the path to the dll's I'm trying to do it as indicated. 
The general steps to install Instant Client are:

1. Download the appropriate Instant Client packages for your platform. All installations require the Basic or Basic Lite package.
2. Unzip the packages into a single directory such as "instantclient_12_1".
3. Set your environment's library loading path (for example LD_LIBRARY_PATH on Linux, or PATH on Windows) to the directory created in Step 2.
4. Start your application.

But I'm stuck at point 3: the windows should look like the following:

[image]

I'm just making a right click on my project and then go to properties in the solution explorer.But I just get the following window:

[image]

(I'm just making a right click on my project and then go to properties in the solution explorer.)

What am I doing wrong? (And gosh, yeah I know I hate visual studio but this is an obligation by owr teacher. Linux is this much simpler...) 
Thanks for any help, the initial idea is to make an project where I can work with oracle but it tells me I got the wrong version. (Another annoying thing from Windows..)

Comment: The image you linked that it "should" look like is for a VC++ project, not a C# one.

Comment: So how to include the PATH from the downloaded oracle files in the project? Aren't the windows all the same? I don't get any of visual studio...

Comment: *"It is used for popular languages and environments including Node.js, Python and PHP, as well as providing access for OCI, OCCI, JDBC, ODBC and Pro*C applications."* I don't see C# in that list... Are you just trying to connect to an Oracle database?

Comment: Yes, I would like to connect to a database using C#.. but when I tried I got an error message that the oracle instant client wasn't the good one (64 mode running but 32 bit client installed)

Comment: Just use nuget to install the Oracle driver: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/

Comment: Just added that as you mentionned, but still get the same error. I have strictly speaking no idea where I have to change what... And to say, I have to connect myself to the oracle server of the school..

Comment: If you are trying to connect your Visual Studio to an Oracle database, you should have a look at this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2009/07/18/connecting-to-oracle-from-visual-studio.aspx).

Comment: Well first, where is the " environment's library loading path ", where can I find it? In my project properties? in the IDE properties? There are hundreds of options....